# Browsers are ignoring my /etc/hosts on Mac. How to fix that?

Tags: mac, dns

My /etc/hosts file is properly formatted.

Even restarting my computer did not help.

When I ping the domain resolves correctly, so /etc/hosts is working.

What can I do? I want to change www.mydomain.com to 127.0.0.1 for example.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a web proxy?

Comment: Nope. It looks like the browsers bypass the /etc/hosts file for some reason.

Comment: Then we've nothing to go on. "My /etc/hosts file is properly formatted." How about letting us see if you're right, at least. How did you change it? take perms, copied it, used GasMask etc? Also, what OS & Mac, specifically?